# Get all unique combinations from list of permutations

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

**TL/DR**

Given `X = {(A,B),(B,C),(D,E),(B,A),(C,B)}` (where `X` is a `set`)

How do I filter for the subtuples which show a unique combination (instead of a unique permutation) such that `X` becomes
`{(A,B),(B,C),(D,E))}`

**Longer form**

Somewhat of an inverse problem from most of the combination/permutation questions on here.

I have a set of tuples (outer tuples), where each tuple has 2 elements, both of which are also tuples (inner tuples), and each sub-tuple has two elements, both of which are integers.

As an example, the set with three elements might look like

```
X = { ( (1,2),(2,3) ), ( (1,3),(1,2) ), ( (2,3),(1,2) ) }
```

While all the outer tuples are unique, I'd like to build a subset which contains the set of unqiue tuples where the ORDER of the two inner tuples is irrelevant (i.e. a set of unique combinations). In the example above this would reduce to;

```
X = { ( (1,2),(2,3) ), ( (1,3),(1,2) )}
```

Because

```
( (1, 2),(2,3) ) and ( (2,3),(1,2) ) )
```

are both just combinations of `(1, 2)` and `(2,3)`.

There are obvious brute-force/for-loop approaches to this but they don't feel very Pythonic.

Maybe leveraging `itertools` and `map`?

Comment: `X = {(A,B),(B,C),(D,E),(B,A),(C,B))}` is not a valid syntax

Comment: @Sudipta `X = { ( (1,2),(2,3) ), ( (1,3),(1,2) ), ( (2,3)(1,2) ) }`

Comment: @Sudipta - sorry an extra ')' snuck in there (corrected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the `sorted` function on your elements using `map` and then use a set comprehension to get the unique elements :

```
>>> new={tuple(i) for i in map(sorted,X)}
>>> new
set([('B', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('D', 'E')])
```

But note that since `sorted` convert your elements to list you need to reverse them to `tuple` because lists are not hashable.

Comment: Nice - yourself and @RemcoGerlich came up with same solution seconds apart - obviously, once your internally order the subtuples everything else is trivial, but I hadn't made that leap. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to *sort* the tuples, then make a new set. (A, B) and (B, A) will both have been sorted to (A, B), and thus only occur once.

```
def to_sorted(t):
    return tuple(sorted(t))

Xnew = {to_sorted(t) for t in X}
```

Another is to not use tuples at all -- tuples are ordered, and you don't care about the order. You could use sets. *frozensets* are immutable sets that can be elements of other sets:

```
Xnew = {frozenset(t) for t in X}
```

I like this slightly better, but 1) it doesn't work if your tuples contain multiples, and 2) now you have frozensets instead of tuples, your other code probably needs changing.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `frozensets` - they may have made more sense for the rest of the code too, actually... Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

One step further simplified (dropping map):

```
new = {tuple(sorted(n)) for n in X}
```